# What is best way to implement a survey in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm planning to create a survey form in Joomla(1.5) that will have a lot of custom fields (name,address, email, date of birth and more...). Now I want to get your opinion on the best approach to do it.   Is there a plugin to easily do that? Or I should really code it from scratch?

Also I want add and integrate some payment gateway that will handle payment (It could be paypal and creditcard). What can be my options for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Survey Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/quiz-a-surveys/7188) might be the way to go for you.

Also there are a host of payment gateway modules you can integrate in your website. You can find them at [joomla extension library](http://extensions.joomla.org).